# Кодировка в парсере RSS

Tags: кодировка, php

Есть такой парсер:

```
$url = 'rss.xml';       //адрес RSS ленты
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);       //Интерпретирует XML-файл в объект

//цикл для обхода всей RSS ленты
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo '<h1>'.$item->title.'</h1>';  //выводим на печать заголовок статьи 
    echo $item->description;  //выводим на печать текст статьи
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы когда парсишь любой сайт, была нормальная кодировка, а не крокозябра?

Answer (score 1):

iconv() в помощь, в каждом xml в заголовке вроде должна быть указана кодировка - попробуй её спарсить первой, а потом - переводи в нужную тебе.